# How Can I call a controller function that is located on another project that is deployed on the same server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, controller

I need to be able to send automatic emails from out website and we are supposed to use this function to do it that is on another project.

```
public class EmailController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Send(SendMailModel mailObj)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["senderEmail"], mailObj.SendingApp);
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailObj.SendTo));
        mail.Subject = mailObj.Subject;
        mail.Body = mailObj.Body;
        // more code
    }
}
```

This email controller is on this site: `services.domain.dev` and our project is deployed on `project.domain.dev`. How should I go about calling this to send emails? I was thinking of an AJAX call on the frontend to try and call it but it doesn't have a route url and I am not allowed to edit this project. Is there a way to communicate with this on the backend from a seperate project deployed on the same server?

**UPDATE:**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SendEmail(string message)
    {
        //Hosted web API REST Service base url  
        string Baseurl = "http://services.domain.dev/";
        SendMailModel mail = new SendMailModel();
        mail.SendTo = "test@email.com";
        mail.Body = message;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Passing service base url  
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            //Define request data format  
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mail), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.PostAsync("api/Email/Send", stringContent);

            //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return Ok(true);
            return Ok(false);
        }
    }
```

I have been trying to use this to be able to communicate with the other controller but I have had no luck. Is there a way to communicate with another controller without using async?

Comment: You just use the same endpoint and call it as a webservice just like you would from client.

Comment: its on a different website, call it like you'd call any other web endpoint

Comment: You probably need to enable to CORS in one of the WebAPI application to allow request from other Please see [enabling cors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII So do you mean call it like: `services.domain.dev/email/mail?data=data`?

Comment: @ChiragMM Thank you for this, I will look into that.

Comment: @BStill Sure.. I'm not sure how the endpoint looks to the client but however it does you just do the same.  There's no harm and if it's on the same machine there won't be any network latency.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I edited my question with a method that I have been trying to get to work. Any thoughts on how I should go about this?

Comment: @Jonesopolis I updated my question with what I have been working on but I still can not seem to get it to work. Any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: “have no luck” and "cannot seem to get it to work" are useless. Describe what exactly happened when you used the updated code above. Read IIS log files to confirm the request message did send out.

Comment: What you're doing should work, at least logically.  You need to make sure the other service is up and running and all.  Can you test it with Postman?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII unfortunately I am not allowed to use Postman. I can only use what is on this dev machine. I believe the service is running because when I go to the url it says that `The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.` I have also tried to use a AJAX to post but I get this error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present`

Comment: Tried to use the `jsonp` dataType to try and get passed the CORS problem with AJAX but it tells me that it does not support GET.

Comment: I getting this error `The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my function was correct. The email API I was connecting to only allowed emails to be sent to dev accounts so I wasn't able to receive it until I sent it to my dev email.